# Dependency Injection of Repository Interface for a Domain Specification Object

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

not sure if I'm just too tired and missing something so apologies in advance.

I have a php domain which I need to restructure because ended having an anemic model using services. This is because I'm not using Doctrine but Eloquent by Laravel as my mapper (reasons are due to linking to other different DB server types)

My reviewed structure needs to be something similar to do this: ( I'm only including a couple of things for this example)

Template Entity has TemplateName as VO.
The TemplateName must satisfy 2 specs. Has to be more than 3 chars long and has to be unique.

I am using a TemplateRepositoryInterface to check the uniqueness and the interface has an Eloquent implementation bounded in a service provider.

Therefore the Template Entity has a method:

```
public function create()
    {
        if ($this->meetsTemplateNameSpecification())
        {
            //fire events etc... saving to repo is done one step above from a service that call this class and gets $this to send tot he interface


            return $this;
        }

        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Template name is not valid.");
    }
```

Then my meetsTemplateNameSpecification method:

```
private function meetsTemplateNameSpecification($originalTemplateName = null)
    {
        $templateNameSpecification = new TemplateNameSpecification($this->name, $originalTemplateName);

        if($templateNameSpecification->isMet())
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Before this restructure, a service was initiating all these and passing the RepositoryInterface to them so that was easy. However, this way I don't know how and /or where to pass or inject the interface because if I have it injected from the container to the Specification class then I cannot initiate from the Entity and I cannot inject the Spec class to the entity either because i want to be able to use it's constructor.

I find it very hard to do in PHP and Active Record with keeping a separation of concerns and not having a dependency on persistence in the domain.

Does anyone have a better structure? Let me know if you need more code please.
So far the only solution that comes to mind is to have static methods in my specification objects so that they do not need to be initiated and I can inject the Repo dependency from the container. Is this the way to go or there's better ways that work with PHP. I hate having to inject from the container to the Domain too but don't think there's any better way unless you're using a different architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating things.

Specification pattern is cool if used in a very general method signature that takes specifications as parameters, or if you have a whole family of specifications. With just one or two particular conditions to test, it might be overkill.

Also, trying to inject a Repository into a domain object (as I guess you are) may be causing you more trouble than good. String length is most probably not a domain rule and uniqueness [may not be either](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/05/19/validation-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/). You might be better off checking those constraints at the Application Service (or Controller) level, directly calling the Repository there for uniqueness, which will spare you all the injection trouble.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if I didn't explain well enough. I used those as easy examples for all the domain rules. These are just basic rules (except the uniqueness which must be a business rule). Don't worry I have several validation in other layers. The domain itself has several other important rules and this is just one context of the object. My question is not about pattern but about implementation. Does this make sense? The question is...how to avoid having the model dependent on the repository or minimize as much as possible. If it's possible to avoid it completely then well and good :)

Comment: In my experience, 95% of domain rules you don't need a Repository for, because they are about a single Aggregate and the Aggregate Root has everything at hand to enforce them.

Comment: 5% of domain logic may occur outside a given Aggregate (mostly in Domain Services) but then again you can pass the Service the domain objects it needs rather than a Repository.

Comment: Thanks but as you can see this rule in particular does depend on repository since it has to check if the name exists from within it. This is obviously a simple example, another one would to check the customer's UID from an external DB. I think I'd rather have a dependency on my repo interface than the service.

Comment: Checking the customer's UID from an external DB doesn't look at all like domain stuff to me. If you really want to enforce name unicity from within the domain, I'd recommend you do it in a Domain Service.

Comment: ... anyway, I'm just suggesting a DDD-idiomatic approach to all that. With regards to your injection issues, I don't quite get why you insist on instantiating the `Specification` in the `Entity`. Doing all the wireup outside the domain and then passing a ready-to-use `Specification` to the `Entity` seems so much simpler.

Comment: thanks for all your comments. As you might of noticed this doesn't fit with my scenario because I don't want to pass the specification as a dependency to the entity because they vary on the process at hand. However with your last comment you explained how this should normally be done. So if you edit your answer as explained in your comment then I can close the question. Thanks once again.

Comment: The GUID is a VO created from several other data so that it has valuable meaning to this context. Sorry I cannot explain more than that!